# How to configure SQL 2008 R2 Express to allow remote machine to connect to it?

Tags: xenapp, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm building a new XenApp 6.5 Farm, which requires SQL 2008 R2 Express(which I've installed on a machine called vCitrixServices). I installed XenApp on vCitrix1 and started to creating a new farm, but I get this error trying to connect to our database.

DB server : vCitrixServices

[image: XenApp DB Error on a new citrix server]

I can connect using MS SQL Management Studio on the DB server using just the server name. (The SQL Server Service says the instance is called MSSQLSERVER)

[image: MS SQL Management Studio - Login Screen]

I tried on my machine with Navicat Premium, and I get this error.

[image: Navicat Premium Error - On my machine]

Things I tried that didn't work :

- All the services are enabled (SQL Server/SQL Server Browser and Client Protocols[ TCP/IP, Named Pipes, VIA])
- Remote connection were enabled.
- Added rules to windows firewall on vCitrixServices(and even turned it off altogether)
- checked all network connection from vCitrix1 and my machine, no problems there.
- Ran cliconfg.exe, and Named Pipes & TCP/IP are both enabled with priority to Named Pipes
- Named Pipes had a default pipe of "sql\query" Couldn't find if that was a problem or not.
- Client Tools & DB Engine were installed. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360141/how-to-connect-to-local-instance-of-sql-server-2008-express)

I've done a few more things, but don't remember them all... I'll update the question with the results of any new test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted all the services then I restarted the SQL Server service. Which fixed the problem and allowed me to connect remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the instance name to the server name i.e.  vCitrixServices\sqlexpress